# Struct with pointer in other struct (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

So, I have this 2 structs and the one global variable

```
struct Tasks{

    int tid;                      
    int difficulty;               
    struct Tasks *next;           
};

struct Head_GL{

    int tasks_count[3];           
    struct Tasks *head;           
};

struct Head_GL *tasks_head;
```

and I have to create a linked list with acceding order by difficulty. How is it possible to make comparision and read the difficulty. I did this `tasks_head->head->difficulty` and gives me segmentation fault

Comment: You will need to allocate memory to them first.

Comment: tasks_head->head=(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks)); like this?

Comment: You also need allocation for `tasks_head`.

Comment: so before i allocate tasks_head->head i have to allocate tasks_head tasks_head=(struct Head_GL*)malloc(sizeof(struct Head_GL));

Comment: @ΗροδοτοςΑποστολου Yes.

Comment: You can drop the casts, they are useless: `(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks))` -> `malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks))`

Comment: okay. Thank you. I will try it right now

Comment: You also need to show your failing code, not only mention `tasks_head->head->difficulty`, which may be correct or not, depending on the context. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create each item:

```
tasks_head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Head_GL));
tasks_head->head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Tasks));
```

You can then populate and use them. You also need to remember to free these later.

Comment: The structs (does he need typedefs around that too...)

Comment: They should be `struct Head_GL` and `struct Tasks`.

Answer (score 0):

I allocate the memory but i have a problem to printf the results. Segmantation fault in printf in main (tasks_head->head->tid). Any help?

```
struct Tasks *new=(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks));


tasks_head=(struct Head_GL*)malloc(sizeof(struct Head_GL));
tasks_head->head=(struct Tasks*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tasks));

tasks_head->tasks_count[0]=0;
tasks_head->tasks_count[1]=0;
tasks_head->tasks_count[2]=0;
tasks_head->head->difficulty=0;
tasks_head->head->tid=0;
tasks_head->head->next=NULL;

if(new==NULL)
    return 0;
new->tid = tid;
new->difficulty = difficulty;
new->next = NULL;

if(difficulty==1)
    tasks_head->tasks_count[0]++;
else if(difficulty==2)
    tasks_head->tasks_count[1]++;
else
    tasks_head->tasks_count[2]++;


if(tasks_head==NULL){
    tasks_head->head = new;
    return 1;
}
if( tasks_head->head->difficulty > difficulty){
    new->next = tasks_head->head;
    tasks_head->head= new;
    return 1;
}
else{
    prev = tasks_head->head;
    temp = tasks_head->head->next;
    while(temp != NULL && temp->difficulty < difficulty){
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp==NULL){
        prev->next = new;
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        new->next = temp;
        prev->next = new;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

int main(){

```
printf("hello1\n");

if(1==insert_task(1,1))
    printf("alo");

if(1==insert_task(4,1))
    printf("alo");

if(1==insert_task(3,2))
    printf("alo\n");


printf("%d\n",num);

for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    printf("%d\n",tasks_head->head->tid);
    tasks_head->head=tasks_head->head->next;
}

return 0;
```

}